# Linear Combination of two trig functions

Tags: trigonometry

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYRoj.jpg) Please click this 1 to see the attached picture. I am adding two trig function but don't know how to show my working for linear combination of the two. We are expected to use $r\cos(x-\alpha)$.

The two functions are $(2700\cos(\frac{\pi}{32}(x-49))+4900)$
and $(1000\cos(\frac{\pi}{32}(x-10))+4000)$.

I know that the period is the same and that the vertical shift is going to be 8900.

The technique that is supposed to be used is:
$a\cos x+b\sin x = R\cos(x−α)$, but it seems difficult to format this into that!
Help would be much appreciated :-)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYRoj.jpg

Comment: Why is it difficult? It's already in the correct form, you have $a$ and $b$ and $\alpha$, you just have to apply the procedure and you're done.

Comment: @orion Probably because there's a phase difference between the two angles.

Comment: Sorry if I'm missing something blatantly obvious but I don't see how they're in the same form. The equations I have include period and y-shift. Sorry again and thanks for helping :-)

Comment: If this bothers you, you can split each cosine with addition formula to cos+sin so you get pure x, then add them together, and apply the formula you have.

Comment: @orion I have attached a picture of what I have done so far. I hope you can see it. I'm not too sure what to do next.

Comment: @AritraDas I hope you've seen the picture. I was just wondering if you could help, please? I have been trying to solve this for quite some time now and help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok let's just deal with this. Write $2700=A$, $1000=B$, $-49\pi/32=x_A$, $-10\pi/32=x_B$ and $\pi x/32=y$. We need

$$A\cos(y+x_A)+B\cos(y+x_B)=$$
$$A\cos y \cos x_A - A \sin y \sin x_A + B \cos y \cos x_B - B \sin y \sin x_B$$
$$\cos y \underbrace{(A\cos x_A+B \cos x_B)}_C-\sin y \underbrace{(A \sin x_A +B \sin x_B)}_D$$

Now continue with your formula. You can even apply it to C and D too, you'll see things simplify a little bit (below you'll see how) :)

---

HOWEVER! There's a better way. Complex numbers of course. Consider this as a real part of
$$Ae^{i(y+x_A)}+Be^{i(y+x_B)}=e^{iy}(Ae^{i x_A}+Be^{ix_B})$$
The parenthesized term is the complex amplitude, so you can simply write down:

$$R=|Ae^{ix_A}+B e^{ix_B}|=\sqrt{A^2+B^2+2AB\cos (x_A-x_B)}$$
(notice the cosine law)
$$-\alpha=\arg (Ae^{ix_A}+B e^{ix_B})=\arctan \frac{A\sin x_A+B\sin x_B}{A\cos x_A+B\cos x_B}$$
where you have to be careful about the quadrant of arctan.

Comment: Thank you for that :). I'm not too familiar with the second method so I'll try the first one.

Comment: Complex numbers are magic, it solves all the trig problems without memorizing any formulas. But anyway... you can use the final results without knowing where they came from.

Comment: @orion -- _I apologize for resurrecting this post, but..._ In what class would one learn about the theory used in the second method?

Comment: @SirJony Depends on the country and type of school. Complex numbers are usually encountered in late high school (year 3 or 4 maybe)... however, the use of the exponential form is more commonly first taught on the university level (most natural science and technical studies cover all the math essentials in first year). The course can be called precalculus or analysis, or just mathematics.